# Rendering dynamic components from Pinia doesn't work with :is

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, pinia

I have this code.  It works fine except when it goes to render my simple components. In fact when I click on tabs, all Pinia works, but it breaks on rendering component.

**this is the Pinia store:**

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useTabs = defineStore('tabs',  {
  state: () => {return{
    ready: false,
    selected: {},
    list:[
        {
            name: "Pubblicazione",
            icon: "fas fa-image",
            component: () => import('@Squadrario/Views/Pubblicazione.vue')
        },
        {
            name: "Edit",
            icon:"fas fa-music",
            component: () => import('@Squadrario/Views/Edit.vue')
        },
    ],
  }},
  getters: {
    isActive: (state) => {
        return (id) => state.selected.name == state.list[id].name
    },
    activeComponent: (state) => {
        return state.selected.component;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    init(){
      this.selected = this.list[0];
      this.ready = true;
    },
    activate(id){
        this.selected = this.list[id];
    },
  },
})
```

Instead this is **the main component**

```
<script setup>
/* imports */
import { ref, onBeforeMount,markRaw } from 'vue'
import { storeToRefs} from 'pinia'

/* stores */
import { useTabs } from './stores/tabs.js';
const tabs = useTabs();
const { isActive } = storeToRefs(tabs);
const { activeComponent } = storeToRefs(tabs);

onBeforeMount(() => {
    tabs.init();
  })
</script>
<template>
    <div v-if="tabs.ready" class="tabs is-toggle is-centered">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="(item,id) in tabs.list" :class="{'is-active': isActive(id)}" @click="tabs.activate(id)">
                <a>
                    <span class="icon is-small"><i :class="item.icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <Transition>
        <keep-alive>
            <component :is="activeComponent"></component>
        </keep-alive>
    </Transition>
</template>
<style>
</style>
```

These are the two components that I'd like to render with tabs:

```
/* a simple component Pubblicazione.vue */

<template>
    PUBBLICAZIONE
</template>
```

```
/* another simple component Edit.vue */

<template>
    EDIT
</template>
```

Why when I change page in tabs I obtain an error `TypeError: d is null ...`?
I think that my mistake is in `<component :is="activeComponent"></component>`
May you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list `component` property is technically just an import function and not the actual component. It should be wrapped in [defineAsyncComponent](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html) to actually load and retrieve the component when needed.

```js
list: [
  {
    name: 'Pubblicazione',
    icon: 'fas fa-image',
    component: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@Squadrario/Views/Pubblicazione.vue')
  },
  {
    name: 'Edit',
    icon: 'fas fa-music',
    component: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@Squadrario/Views/Edit.vue')
  }
]
```

Also for performance the getter should return the raw component object

```js
activeComponent: state => {
  return toRaw(state.selected.component)
}
```